# Are these arguments correct?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have an $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ function $h(x_1,x_2, x_3)$, and I know that 
$$ \begin{aligned} 
&\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x_1}}=0, \\
&\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x_2}}=\rho(x_1,x_2),\\
&\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x_3}}=c,
\end{aligned} $$
where $c$ is a constant and $\rho(x_1,x_2)$ is a function that is independent of $x_3$.

I have the following arguments:
$$\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x_1}} = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2{h}}{\partial{x_2}\partial{x_1}} =0 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{x_1}}=0 \Rightarrow\rho(x_1,x_2)=\rho(x_2),$$
i.e. I claim that $\rho$ is independent of $x_1$. And finally $h=cx_3 + \phi(x_2)$ with $\phi^\prime(x_2)=\rho(x_2)$.

Are these arguments correct?

Comment: You need to know that $h$ is twice differentiable to say the above.

Comment: Taisuke Yasuda, I can assume that $h$ is twice differentiable. However, if we assume that $h$ is differentiable only once, can there be an example where $\rho$ depends on $x_1$?